# Template Toolkit browser detection

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

Is there a way to detect what browser you are using through template toolkit?  For example I can achieve what I want to do using jQuery but thought it would be useful to know how to do it in template toolkit if possible?

Jquery

```
    <script>
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
        if ( (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version < 9.0) )
        {
            jQuery('body').addClass('old-ie');
        }
    });
    </script>
```

In template toolkit I want to do something like the below but can't see this in the documentation anywhere?

```
    <body 
    [% IF browser.msie && browser.version < 9.0 %]
    class="old-ie"
    [% ELSE %]
    [% END %]
    >
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of a TT plug-in for this, but it's trivial to add a line or two to your back-end application to make the information available to the template. For example, if your app is Catalyst based, you would add something like this to your main program:

```
__PACKAGE__->apply_request_class_roles(qw/
    Catalyst::TraitFor::Request::BrowserDetect
/);
```

... and in your 'auto' handler, introduce a line such as (untested):

```
$c->stash(browser => $c->req->browser);
```

... or just use this is your template:

```
[%- SET browser = c.req.browser;
    SET old_ie = 'class="old-ie"'
        IF browser.windows && browser.ie && browser.public_major < 9.0;
-%]
```

and then include `old_ie` wherever it's required in your template.

See [Catalyst::TraitFor::Request::BrowserDetect](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aTraitFor%3a%3aRequest%3a%3aBrowserDetect) and [HTTP::BrowserDetect](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aBrowserDetect) for more info and options. I'm sure there are similar plugins/methods for Dancer, Mojolicious etc.

Answer (score 4):

You could do that through the HTTP request headers.  You didn't mention what was calling TT, but if you're using Catalyst, you could use [Catalyst::TraitFor::Request::BrowserDetect](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aTraitFor%3a%3aRequest%3a%3aBrowserDetect), and then pass a variable to TT to say what kind of browser was requesting the page.